# share tomcat logs using tomcat http service

Tags: http, tomcat, hyperlink, fileshare, ln

In our testing enviornment (Linux), we use tomcat http service to share logs. for example,

In tomcat/webapps/ROOT, ln -s tomcat/logs share-log, then everyone can access tomcat logs http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/share-log

But I have issue with one tomcat server. If I create file link, ln -s tomcat/logs/catalina.out share-log, then everyone can acess http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/share-log (this is catalina.out). However, if I create a directory link, ln -s tomcat/logs share-log, now the logs points to the directory, but it replied HTTP Stauts 404 /share-log is not available.

I compared files owners and permissions, couldn't find anything wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/share-log you'll get 404 because there is not a index.html inside tomcat/logs.

Did you try to check if http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/share-log/catalina.out is working?

Comment: Thanks. http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/share-log/catalina.out replied 404 as well. I created directory /tomcat/webapps/ROOT/test with a few files, http://tomcatip.domain.com:8080/test shows all the files. I think for some reason, the link is not work with http on this server. But why?